# how to pass optional arguments and datatypes to a method without triggering error PHP

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to pass date values to a method in my repository files to be used as an option to query my database.

Im working on a Symfony project.

basically, what I'm trying at the moment is in my controller

```
// send my dates to repository
    $result = $entityManager->getRepository(Repository1::class)->getData($start, $end);
```

and then in my repository I try to receive it in my getData method

```
/**
     * @param bool|null $data
     * @param string|null $start
     * @param string|null $end
     * @return MountPort[]
     */


    public function getData(bool $data = null,$start = null, $end = null)
    {
//trying to collect dates here to work with

}
```

But then i keep getting this error

```
Repository1::getData() must be of the type bool or null, object given, called in.
```

please what can I do to enable my dates passed without the bool data type error triggering

Please is string the right data type for dates or im also doing that wrong?

Please note I also tried passing the string data type like this, but that didn't fly too

```
public function getData(bool|string $data = null,$start = null, $end = null)
        {
```

error I got

```
syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)
```

Comment: Arguments are assigned in order, not by variable name. So when you call `getData($start, $end)` it's using `$start` as the value of parameter `$data` and `$end` as the value of parameter `$start`.

Comment: Well the argument order is wrong. If you want to pass in `$start` and `$end` without the first argument you can do: ->getData(null, $start, $end)`. If you have PHP 8 you can also use named arguments instead: `->getData(start: $start, end: $end)`

Comment: Even then you will have the problem, that `$start` and `$end` according to the comment block should be strings not DateTime-objects. You will probably still have to make some changes or call `$start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` (or something like it) at some point to get the datetime formatted as a string

Comment: @Barmar and dbrumann I still need the $data variable passed so if I change the arrangement won't that affect the $data variable with utilizes the bool. please what would you recommend I do to accommodate all three arguments and their data type. I work with php 7.3

Comment: Before PHP 8, you can't skip arguments, you can only omit arguments at the end of the argument list.

Answer (score 1):

Like dbrumann said,
In your example, you don't use $data so I assume you don't need it, you just have to define it to null in your controller and keep the bool in your function arguments.

```
$result = $entityManager->getRepository(Repository1::class)->getData(null, $start, $end);

public function getData(bool $data = null, $start = null, $end = null)
{}
```